# Do I need to change URL in my pages while rewriting URL's

Tags: php, url-rewriting

I am using a simple rule to rewrite a URL

```
RewriteRule   home.htm   home.php
```

And I've a menu where currently URL is

```
<a href="home.php">Home</a>
```

So should I change that `href` or am doing something wrong? Or there is a way where URL's in a page are changed automatically.

Comment: maybe you could change it to `/home.php` so it always start at the root.

Comment: It depends, what do you want the end user to actually see in their browser?

Comment: using home.php in html would save your server having to rewrite in the first place.

Comment: @MarcB Actually I served a simple example here, in real sense what I want to do is to make `www.domain.com/home.php` to `www.domain.com/home`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `a href`, because you are rewriting `php`  to `html`

```
<a href="home.htm">Home</a>
```

Comment: So how does Joomla changes all it's un-friendly urls   to friendly once even if you write urls in an article? so do you mean i need to change all urls

Comment: @RandomGuy yah you need to change all urls

Answer (score 0):

You can link to either home.htm or home.php.  Your RewriteRule will load home.php in either case.  If it was me, I'd link to home.php since that's the actual page that is being loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, it depends on you. Or if the index of your site is `/home.htm`, surely, it's better to link the index. And example, if `/home.htm` is rewritten into `/pages/home.htm`, it's better to link `/home.htm`. I suggest that you link your `/home.htm` because you wouldn't rewrite it if you don't have an interest to it. YOU WANT `.htm` BETTER THAN `.php` SUCH LIKE OTHERS!!

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use style sheets and such things in your pages you have to address them all absolute. Simply define a constant `define('ABS_PATH', 'your website address')` at first of your page, then whenever you want to address something within your website use it at the first part of the URL:

e. g.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo ABS_PATH; ?>/styles/style.css" />
```

I usually address all of the internal links with this constant either simple links or styles.